# assign a variable value to dynamic c array

Tags: c, arrays, variable-assignment

Hello I want to assing my count value to this 'ob' structs 'p_id' variable. How can I do that? I read other values from file but I need an id for selection and I use count for that. But I don't know how to assing it.

My .txt file;

> 0 0
>
> 0 1
>
> 1 1

```
FILE *fp;

struct ob{ 
   int x;
   int y;
   int p_id;
};
struct ob* ptr;
int count=0;


ptr = (struct ob*)malloc(sizeof(struct ob));
while(!feof(fp))
{
  ++count;
  fscanf (fp,"%d%d%d", &ptr->x, &ptr->y, &ptr->p_id=count); /* in here I want to assing count to p_id */
  printf("%d %d %d",ptr->x, ptr->y, ptr->p_id);
  
 }
  fclose (fp);
}
```

Comment: Simply make up your mind if you want to read `p_id` from the file or overwrite it with `count`. If you want the fscanf read to be a "dummy read", then simply do `ptr->p_id = count;` on a line of its own after fscanf.

Comment: I do not have any p_id in file. I need to add that after I read file. If I do like I did on my question code compiler gives me an error (error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment)

Comment: can you show a snippet of the context of your file ?

Comment: If you don't have pid in the file, what is it you want to read with 3rd `%d`?

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to assign a sequence number to `ptr->p_id`, remove it from the `fscanf` call and assing the value after it:

```
 fscanf (fp,"%d%d", &ptr->x, &ptr->y);
 ptr->p_id=count;
```

If you want the value to be optional, you can move the assignment before the call and let `fscanf` overwrite it if it's present:

```
 ptr->p_id=count;
 fscanf (fp,"%d%d%d", &ptr->x, &ptr->y, &ptr->p_id);
```

The return value of `fscanf` allows you to see if the value was updated or not:

```
RETURN VALUE
       On success, these functions return the number of input items
       successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided
       for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.
```